# How $\cos^2 (2x))^2 = \frac14(1+\cos (4x))^2$

Tags: trigonometry

Can you please give me the proof for $\cos^2 (2x))^2 = \frac14(1+\cos (4x))^2$.

I know that $\frac12(\cos (2x) + 1) = \cos^2 x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the identity you already know, we can use that

$$\cos (4x)=\cos^2(2x)-\sin^2(2x)=2\cos^2(2x)-1$$

then

$$1+\cos (4x)=2\cos^2(2x)$$